# Sync database on ipad with remote database

Tags: mysql, ipad, synchronization

I have an ipad app that has a database. I created a web-service on my mac mini using php,apache,mysql.

What I would like to do is sync the database on the ipad with the one I have on the remote computer maybe once everyday. Can someone please provide me with an example,sample code or even advice on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would need more info to give you an accurate answer. What kind of database are you using ?

I can only give you a general answer since you really don't provide a lot of info, 
What you would usually do when you need to send/request data from iOS to a Web Service, is send an HTTP Request using `NSURLConnection` or other wrapper  classes such as AFNetwork.

Also the term "syncing" is quite a big subject, what do you mean by syncing? Always making sure the data on the iOS Database is the same as the web service database? If so you could have the client save some sort of E-Tag (last modified date), and ask the server only for data from that day onwards. Or the other way around, depends on the type of syncing you wish to accomplish.

I hope some of this makes sense for you, since your question was really general, my answer features a bit of general info , but might be helpful for you :)

Comment: the database is MYSQL on the remote computer and the database on the ipad is Sqlite. When i say sync i basically want to update the database on the remote server. If a record was added,deleted or edited, i want to reflect that change in the database on the remote server. any sample code you can give?

Comment: I dont have any sample code on hand but what you can do is have a simple PHP file that accept certain "actions". For example: updateUser, addUser, deleteUser, or any other action that can be relevant to you , and update the MySQL Database. You can learn more about sending HTTP Requests with AFNetwork here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking or with NSURLRequest http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: do you have any ideas on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775103/insert-into-remote-database-asiformdatarequest-getting-400-code-bad-request